# Unable to merge the cell with LINQ and UiPath

Tags: excel, linq, merge, cell, uipath

I am unable to find the solution for merging the cell by LINQ and as well in UiPath.
For your reference I'm attaching the screen shot.
I have this,

[image: Problem]

I want this,

[image: Solution]

Just need the solution in LINQ or UiPath.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [groupby](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-7.0) method in LinQ.

In your case it will be like this:

```
(someDT.AsEnumerable.
    GroupBy(Function (row) row.Field(Of String)("SN")).
    Select(Function (grp) grp.CopyToDataTable)
).ToList
```

After it you will recieve a list of datatables grouped by SN Field, and you'll be able to work with them as with separated datatables using for each.